# iCal/Calendar and GMail - constantly errors and problems

Tags: ical, calendar, gmail, google-calendar

I'm using iCal/Calendar on MacOSX 10.8.2 and have one main account on GMail. It mostly works.

However, about every 1 minute - 12 hours (it really varies a lot), I get some errors from iCal that it couldn't find the CalDAV calendar or it got error 404. But then it works again. (It looks similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16080/sync-errors-between-ical-and-google-calendars) error although the suggestions there don't help me.)

Also, in addition to that, I have some sub-calendars (e.g. for birthdays). Mostly they show up in iCal, sometimes also twice (and then I have all entries double) and sometimes they completely disappear.

This is really annoying. So annoying that I want to have this resolved or I must find an alternative to iCal. I don't always want to click 'ok' on this error dialog. I also don't want to hope for luck that it shows my sub-calendars.

Is there some way to fix this? Or what are good alternatives to iCal?

Comment: What version of OS X/iOS are you running? By the way, I recommend you accept some of your question's answers.

Comment: @bassplayer7: MacOSX 10.8.2. I really would like to accept more. I read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/unanswered-questions-and-accept-rate). For most of the answers on my questions so far, I feel that they don't perfectly answer my question in a way that they provided the information/solution I was searching for.

Answer (score 2):

The [last post on the first page of this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4274995?start=45&tstart=0) states it is a known Google problem. (I haven't personally verified its accuracy, though).

Quoting @Kjell-o:

> Just so everyone is aware. The issue is indeed in Google's system, not in iCal. They are working on a solution. I received this directly from their enterprise support. If you look at the calendar logs, you'll see a ton of error for the calendar service - I'm getting ones that say, premature EOF.
>
> On another note, the google forums say that the shared calendars no longer act as "delegates" but as normal calendars and as a result they show up in the regular list. This may be the "duplicates" that some people are receiving. If this is you, uncheck the delegates as those will be superflous and most likely the cause of the 404 messages.